# Shouldn't unit tests use my own methods?

Tags: programming-practices, unit-testing, code-reuse

Today I was watching a "[JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) basics" video and the author said that when testing a given method in your program, you shouldn't use other of your own methods in the process.

To be more specific, he was talking about testing some record-creation method that took a name and last name for arguments, and it used them to create records in a given table. But he claimed that in the process of testing this method, he shouldn't use his other [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) methods to query the database to check the final result (to check that record was indeed created with the right data). He claimed that for that, he should write additional [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) code to query the database and check the result.

I think I understand the spirit of his claim: you don't want one method's test case to depend on the correctness of the other methods (in this case, the DAO method), and this is accomplished by writing (again) your own validation/supporting code (which should be more specific and focussed, hence, simpler code).

Nonetheless, voices inside my head started protesting with arguments like code duplication, unnecessary additional efforts, etc. I mean, if we run the whole test battery, and we test all our public methods thoroughly (including the DAO method in this case), shouldn't it be OK to just use some of those methods while testing other methods? If one of them is not doing what it's supposed to, then its own test case will fail, and we can fix it and run the test battery again. No need for code duplication (even if the duplicate code is somewhat simpler) or wasted efforts.

I have an strong feeling about this because of several recent [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)-[VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) applications I've written (properly unit-tested thanks to [Rubberduck for VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com)), where applying this recommendation would mean a lot of additional extra work, with no perceived benefit.

Can you please share your insights about this?

Comment: It's slightly strange to see a unit test that involves the database at all

Comment: IMO it's fine to call other classes IFF they're fast enough. Mock anything that has to go to disk or over a network. There's no sense in mocking a plain ol' class IMO.

Comment: Have a link to this video?

Comment: @RichardTingle don't take the example to literally please. You could just substitute for a different example where some data parsing is done before processing file contents. The file parsing is done by some (reusable) class. The file processing is done by another. And that is just one example that comes to mind right away.

Comment: @RubberDuck: I wouldn't say mock everything that goes to disk, just operations that are likely to cause trouble (admittedly, that's most of them). Something that reads and writes to temp files in the standard temp file location, might as well do the real deal.

Comment: @carlossierra, in your recent example, a pure unit test would isolate and remove the parsing entirely. Your processing class would have a dependency on the parsing class (or interface), which you would mock away during a test so that you only cared about how the processing class dealt with the parsed data. This isn't to be confused with duplicating code -- you aren't -- the parsing logic only lives in the parsing class, but you simply are not doing any parsing. You fake whatever you have to so that you can test the processing logic independently.

Comment: @CandiedOrange sure. But I don't want this to be taken as an attack to the video's author, since I have enjoyed and learned a lot from all his videos on this course. The course is called "Java Design Patterns and Arquitecture" by John Purcell, and can be found in Udemy. Go to lesson 14 "JUnit Basics: Testing the DAO" @ 13:40.

Comment: JUnit was written by hardcore unit-test-purists who refrained on purpose from providing any means of specifying the order in which tests would be executed.  Their justification for not providing this had always been "you should not need that, because your tests should not depend on each other".  Well, sorry, but to all non-purists, ***they do***.  ("non-purists" = people who are pragmatic rather than dogmatic.)

Comment: Not looking to attack.  Looking for clear context.

Comment: @CandiedOrange yes, after reading many of your posts here, I think I know that. I was just sort of explaining why I didn't provide a reference to the video in my post. I just wanted to make clear that **it's me** who don't intend to attack the author or the course, but just to clarify my doubts. Some peolpe might not see it like that. Sort of a "defensive disclaimer" ;)

Comment: @carlossierra Aw shucks. You're making me blush. :) Video appears to be paywalled.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I think the course is free. Isn't it? Anyway, I think he offers the same course [here](http://courses.caveofprogramming.com/courses/java-design-patterns-and-architecture)

Comment: That's a fair point of view @whatsisname. Personally, I like my tests to be fast. Hitting the file system is slow. It's probably fine to have a few, but having a few hundred that hit the file system will make people not want to run them.

Comment: "*properly unit-tested thanks to Rubberduck for VBA*" - you sir, have just made my day. I'd fix the typo and edit it from "RubberDuck" to "Rubberduck", but I'd feel like some spammer doing that and adding a link to [rubberduckvba.com](http://rubberduckvba.com) (I own the domain name and the co-own the project with @RubberDuck) - so I'll just comment here instead. Anyway it's awesome to see people actually using the tool that's been responsible for most of my sleepless nights for the better part of the past two years! =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug and RubberDuck I love what you are doing with Rubberduck. Please keep it up. Certainly my life is easier because of it (I happen to do a lot of small programs and prototypes in Excel VBA). BTW, the Rubberduck mention in my post was just me trying to be nice to RubberDuck himself, which in turn has been nice to me [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/329178/windows-batch-files-bat-coding-style-standard) in PE. :)

Comment: @carlossierra Both the database and the file example demonstrate the same code smell to me. Logic should be separated from persistence (or any other kind of external edge like making HTTP requests, etc.). The latter should be mockable. Then this whole question goes away. You don't need to worry about re-using or duplicating data access code because there is no data access in your tests. Instead you have a mock that you can just use to directly verify what you want.

Comment: @RichardTingle, perhaps it wouldn't be a "unit test", but rather and "integration test". In any case, I find it very helpful to verify my SQL does what I think it does.

Comment: @Mat'sMug StackExchange doesn't give a frolicking fjord whether or not it's your website or someone else's. All you have to do is 1) make the answer stand on its own, only using the link for support/further reading and 2) declare your affiliation in each and every post that has self-promotion. We only want to stop spammers, not handicap experts.

Comment: It's a lot easier to fix a single bug if a single change causes exactly one test to fail. If it causes many tests to fail it's both harder to find, and while you're fixing it new bugs may be introduced so the unrelated tests continue to fail but now you don't know what change made that happen.

Comment: @BenAaronson Insisting that all such interfaces can be readily mockable can bring problems of its own - what DHH called Test-induced Design Damage (http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The spirit of his claim is indeed correct. The point of unit tests is to isolate code, test it free of dependencies, so that any erroneous behavior can be quickly recognized where it is happening.

With that said, unit testing is a tool, and it is meant to serve your purposes, it is not an altar to be prayed to. Sometimes that means leaving dependencies in because they work reliably enough and you don't want to bother mocking them, sometimes that means some of your unit tests are actually pretty close if not actually integration tests.

Ultimately you're not getting graded on it, what's important is the end product of the software being tested, but you'll just have to be mindful of when you're bending the rules and deciding when the trade-offs are worth it.

Comment: Hooray for pragmatism.

Comment: I would add that is is not some much the reliability as the speed that is the issue that leads to stubbing out dependencies.  The test in isolation mantra is so compelling however that this argument is often missed.

Comment: "... unit testing is a tool, and it is meant to serve your purposes, it is not an altar to be prayed to. " -- this!

Comment: "not an altar to be prayed to" - angry TDD coaches incoming!

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Speed is absolutely a factor, but even if we were willing to put up with the slow down, reliability of those dependencies can be an issue. That's not so much the case for databases hosted inside your network, but how about a REST-ish web service served up by some random county government that goes down all the time? This assumes you build your application to be able to cope with it being down, but you don't want some particular unit test failing once a week because it's down. Whether that poses an issue depends how reliable the service is.

Comment: @jpmc26: even worse you don't want all your unit tests *passing* because they correctly handled the web service being down, which is a valid and correct behaviour, but never actually exercising the code for when it's up! Once you stub it you get to choose whether it's "up" or "down" and test both.

Comment: I put my databases on ramdisk for integration tests (I'm not working with terabytes of data when I run tests), and it's quite fast. Not as fast as no work at all of course, but fast enough for me to be happy.

Comment: `ultimately you're not being graded on it` tell that to my performance reviewers ;)

Comment: @jpmc26, mocking external dependencies is one thing, but if I depended on random web service that goes down all the time, I'd just create a mock for that on internal server, but still use all of the normal http layer. Mocking up lower layers makes sense mainly for _fault injection_, so you can test the higher layer is robust against the lower layer failing. Because obviously you write the normal lower layer not to fail.

Answer (score 36):

I think this comes down to terminology. To many, a "unit test" is a very specific thing, and *by definition* cannot be have a pass/fail condition that depends on any code outside of the *unit* (method, function, etc.) being tested. This would include interaction with a database.

To others, the term "unit test" is much looser, and encompasses any sort of automated testing, including test code that tests integrated portions of the application.

A test purist (if I may use that term) might call that an *integration test*, distinguished from a *unit test* on the basis that the test depends on more than one pure *unit* of code.

I suspect that you are using the looser version of the term "unit test", and are actually referring to an "integration test".

Using those definitions, you shouldn't depend on code outside of the unit under test in a "unit test". In an "integration test", however, it is perfectly reasonable to write a test that exercises some specific piece of code and then inspects the database for the passing criteria.

Whether you should depend on integration tests or unit tests or both is a much larger topic of discussion.

Comment: You are right on your suspicions. I am misusing the terms and I can see now how each type of test can be handled more appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: "To others, the term "unit test" is much looser" -- aside from anything else, so-called "unit testing frameworks" are a really convenient way to organise and run higher-level tests ;-)

Comment: Rather than a "pure" vs "loose" distinction, which is loaded with connotations, I'd suggest the distinction is between those who view "units", "dependencies", etc. from a domain perspective (e.g. "authentication" would count as a unit, "database" would count as a dependency, etc.) vs. those who view them from a programming language perspective (e.g. methods are units, classes are dependencies). I find that defining what is being meant by phrases like "the unit under test" can turn arguments ("You're wrong!") into discussions ("Is this the right level of granularity?").

Comment: @Warbo I agree with you... The point I was trying to make is that the OP's confusion likely stems from a difference in definition of what constitutes a "unit". I was categorizing the definitions as "pure" and "loose" as a way of distinguishing between them, but the ultimate point is that when discussing what's appropriate in a "unit test", it's important to understand what each party means by "unit".

Comment: @EricKing Of course, to the very large majority of those in your first category, the very *idea* of involving the database *at all* in unit tests is anathema, whether you use your DAOs or hit the database directly.

Comment: As much as I agree with this answer, it doesn't really answer the OP's question. May integration tests use production code methods?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga The question was basically "somebody says I shouldn't do this thing in unit tests but I do it in unit tests and I think it's fine. Is that ok?" And my answer was "Yes, but most people would call that an integration test instead of a unit test.". As far as your question, I don't know what you mean by "may integration tests use production code methods?".

Comment: @EricKing OK, I guess I didn't pick up that your answer essentially was a "Yes". Maybe it would be more clear if you put what you wrote in your comment into your answer as a TLDR footnote. What I wrote is just a rephrasing of the OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes and no...

Unique tests that perform in isolation are an absolute must as it allows you to lay down the ground work that your low-level code is functioning appropriately. But in coding larger libraries, you will also find areas of code that will require you have tests that cross units.

These cross-unit tests are good for code coverage and when testing end to end functionality but they do come with a few drawbacks you should be aware of:

- Without an isolated test to confirm just what is breaking, a failed "cross-unit" test will require additional troubleshooting to determine just what is wrong with your code
- Relying too much on cross-unit tests can get you out of the contract mindset that you should always be in when writing SOLID Object-Oriented code. Isolated tests typically make sense because your units should only be performing just one basic action.
- End to end testing is desirable but can be dangerous if a test require you to write to a database or perform some action that you wouldn't want to occur in a production environment. This one of the many reasons why mocking frameworks like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) are so popular because it allows you to fake an object and mimic an end to end test without actually changing something you shouldn't.

At the end of the day you want to have some of both.. a lot of tests that trap low level functionality and a few that test end to end functionality. Focus on the reason why you are writing tests in the first place. They are there to give you confidence that your code is performing the way you expect it to. Whatever you need to do to make that happen is just fine.

The sad but true fact is if you are using automated tests at all then you already have a leg up on a lot of developers. Good testing practices is the first thing to slide when a development team is faced with tough deadlines. So as long as you are sticking to your guns and writing unit tests that are a meaningful reflection of how your code should perform, I wouldn't obsess on just how "pure" your tests are.

Answer (score 4):

One issue with using other object methods to test a condition is that you will miss errors that cancel each other out.  More importantly, you're missing out on the pain of a difficult test implementation, and that pain is teaching you something about your underlying code.  Painful tests now mean painful maintenance later.

Make your units smaller, split your class, refactor, and redesign until it's easier to test *without* reimplementing the rest of your object.  Get some help if you think your code or tests are unable to be simplified any further.  Try to think of a colleague who seems to always luck out and get assignments that are easy to test cleanly.  Ask him or her for help, because it isn't luck.

Comment: Key here is in unit.  If you need to make calls to other procedures and processes it would not be, to me, a unit.  If multiple calls are made and multiple steps need to be validated, then if it a large piece of code than a unit, break it into smaller pieces covering a single piece of logic.  Normally, a DB call would also be mocked or an in memory DB would be used in the unit test over accessing a real DB and needing to undo data after the test.

Answer (score 1):

If the unit of functionality being tested is 'is the data stored persistently and retrievable', then I would have the unit test test that - store to a real database, destroy any objects holding references to the database, then call the code to fetch the objects back.

Testing whether a record is created in the database seems to be concerned with the implementation details of the storage mechanism rather than testing the unit of functionality exposed to the rest of the system.

You might want to shortcut the test to improve performance using a mock database, but I have had contractors who did exactly that and left at the end of their contract with a system which passed such tests, but didn't actually store anything in the database between system reboots.

You can argue whether 'unit' in unit test denotes a 'unit of code' or 'unit of functionality', functionality perhaps created by many code units in concert. I don't find this a useful distinction - the questions I'd keep in mind are 'does the test tell you something about whether the system provides business value', and 'is the test brittle if the implementation changes?' Tests like the one described are useful when you are TDDing the system - you haven't yet written the 'get object from database record' yet so can't test the full unit of functionality - but are brittle against implementation changes so I'd remove them once the full operation is testable.

Answer (score 1):

The spirit is correct.

Ideally, in a *unit test*, you are testing a *unit* (a individual method or small class).

Ideally, you would stub out the whole database system. I.e., you would run your method in a faked environment and just make sure that it calls the correct DB APIs in the correct order. You explicitely, positively do *not* want to test the DB when testing one of your own methods.

Benefits are many. Most of all, tests get blinding fast because you do not need to bother about setting up a correct DB environment and rolling it back afterwards.

Of course, this is a lofty goal in any software project that does not do this right from the get-go. But it is the spirit of *unit* testing.

Note that there are other tests, like feature tests, behaviour tests etc. that are different from this approach - don't confuse "testing" with "unit testing".

Comment: "just make sure that it calls the correct DB APIs in the correct order" — yeah, sure. Until it turns out you've misread the documentation and the actual correct order you should have been using is completely different. Don't mock systems outside of your control.

Comment: @Joker_vD That's what integration tests are for. In unit tests, external systems absolutely should be mocked.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one very important reason *not* to use direct database access in your unit tests for business code that interacts with the database: if you change your database implementation, you'll have to rewrite all of those unit tests.  Rename a column, for your code you just have to change a single line in your data mapper definition.  If you don't use your data mapper while testing, however, you'll then find you also have to change *every single unit test that references this column*.  This could turn into an extraordinary amount of work, particularly for more complex changes that are less amenable to search-and-replaced.

Also, using your data mapper as an abstract mechanism rather than talking to the  database directly makes it easier to *remove the dependency on the database entirely*, which might not be relevant now, but when you get up to thousands of unit tests and all of them are hitting a database, you'll be thankful that you can easily refactor them to remove that dependency because your test suite will drop from taking minutes to run to taking seconds, which can have a huge benefit on your productivity.

Your question indicates that you are thinking along the right lines.  As you suspect, unit tests are code too.  It is just as important to make them maintainable and easy to adapt to future changes as for the rest of your code base.  Strive to keep them readable and to eliminate duplication, and you'll have a much better test suite for it.  And a good test suite is one that gets used.  And a test suite that gets used helps to find errors, while one that doesn't get used is just worthless.

Answer (score 1):

The best lesson I learned when learning about unit testing and integration testing is to not test methods, but test behaviors.  In other words, what does this object do?

When I look at it that way, a method which persists data and another method which reads it back start to be testable.  If you are testing the methods specifically, of course, you end up with a test for each method in isolation such as:

```
@Test
public void canSaveData() {
    writeDataToDatabase();
    // what can you assert - the only expectation you can have here is that an exception was not thrown.
}

@Test
public void canReadData() {
    // how do I even get data in there to read if I cannot call the method which writes it?
}
```

This problem occurs because of the perspective of testing methods.  Don't test methods.  Test behaviors.  What is the behavior of the WidgetDao class?  It persists widgets.  Ok, how do you verify it persists widgets?  Well, what is the definition of persistence?  It means when you write it, you can read it back again.  So read + write together become a test, and in my opinion, a more meaningful test.

```
@Test
public void widgetsCanBeStored() {
    Widget widget = new Widget();
    widget.setXXX.....
    // blah

    widgetDao.storeWidget(widget);
    Widget stored = widgetDao.getWidget(widget.getWidgetId());
    assertEquals(widget, stored);
}
```

That is a logical, cohesive, reliable, and my in opinion, meaningful test.

The other answers focus how important isolation is, the pragmatic versus realistic debate, and whether a unit test may or may not query a database.  Those do not really answer the question though.

To test if something can be stored, you have to store it and then read it back.  You cannot test if something is stored if you are not allowed to read it.  Don't test the storing of data separately from the retrieval of data.  You will end up with tests which don't tell you anything.

Comment: Very insightful approach, and as you say, I think you really hit one of the core doubts I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One example of a failure case you'd prefet to catch, is that the object under test uses a caching layer but fails to persist the data as required. Then if you query the object it'll say "yup, I've got the new name and address", but you want the test to fail because it hasn't actually done what it was supposed to.

Alternatively (and overlooking the single-responsibility violation), suppose it's required to persist a UTF-8-encoded version of the string to a byte-oriented field, but actually persists Shift JIS. Some other component is going to read the database and expects to see UTF-8, hence the requirement. Then the round-trip through this object will report the correct name and address because it'll convert it back from Shift JIS, but the error isn't detected by your test. It hopefully will be detected by some later integration test, but the whole point of unit tests is to catch problems early, and know exactly what component is responsible.

> If one of them is not doing what it's supposed to, then its own test case will fail and we can fix it and run the test battery again.

You can't assume this, because if you're not careful you write a mutually dependent set of tests. The "does it save?" test calls the save method it's testing, and then the load method to confirm it saved. The "does it load?" test calls the save method to set up the test fixture and then the load method it's testing to check the result. Both tests rely on the correctness of the method they aren't testing, meaning that neither of them actually tests the correctness of the method it is testing.

The clue that there's a problem here, is that two tests that supposedly are testing different units *actually do the same thing*. They both call a setter followed by a getter, then check the result is the original value. But you wanted to test that the setter persists the data, not that the setter/getter pair works together. So you know something's wrong, you just have to figure out what and fix the tests.

If your code is well-designed for unit testing, then there are at least two ways you can test whether the data has really been correctly persisted by the method under test:

- mock the database interface, and have your mock record the fact that the proper functions have been called on it, with the expected values. This tests the method does what it's supposed to, and is the classic unit test.
- pass it an actual database with *exactly the same intention*, to record whether or not the data has been correctly persisted. But rather than having a mocked function that just says "yup, I got the right data", your test reads back out of the database directly and confirms it's correct. This may not be the *purest* possible test, because an entire database engine is quite a big thing to use to write a glorified mock, with more chance of me overlooking some subtlety that makes a test pass even though something is wrong (so for example I shouldn't use the same database connection to read as was used to write, because I might see an uncommitted transaction). But it tests the right thing, and at least you know that it *precisely* implements the entire database interface without having to write any mock code!

So it is a mere detail of test implementation whether I read the data out of the test database by JDBC or whether I mock the database. Either way the point is that I can test the unit better by isolating it than I can if I allow it to conspire with other incorrect methods on the same class to look right even when something is wrong. Therefore I want to use any convenient means to check that the correct data was persisted, *other than* trust the component whose method I'm testing.

If your code is *not* well-designed for unit testing, then you may have no choice, because the the object whose method you want to test might not accept the database as an injected dependency. In which case the discussion about the best way to isolate the unit under test, changes into a discussion about how close it's possible to get to isolating the unit under test. The conclusion is the same, though. If you can avoid conspiracies among faulty units then you do, subject to available time and to anything else you think of that would be more effective at finding faults in the code.

Answer (score 0):

*This is how I like to do it. This is just a personnal choice since this won't impact the result of the product, only the way to produce it.*

This depend on the possibilites to be able to add mock values in your database without the application you are testing.

Let's say you have two tests :
A - reading the database
B - insert into the database ( depends on A)

If A pass, then you are sure that the result of B would depends on the part tested in B and not the dependencies.
If A failes, you can have a false negative for B. The error might be in B or in A. You can't know for sure until A return a success.

I would not try to write some queries in a unit-testing since you should not be able to know the DB structure behind the application (or it might change). Meaning your test case could failed because of your code itself. Unless you write a test for the test, but who will test the test for the test...

Answer (score -1):

In the end, it comes down to what you want to test.

Sometimes it is enough to test the provided interface of your class (e.g. record gets created and stored and can be retrieved later, maybe after a "restart"). In this case it is fine (and usually a good idea) to use the provided methods for testing. This enables the tests to be reused, for example if you want to change the storage mechanism (different database, in-memory database for testing, ...).

> Note that this means you only really care that the class is adhering to its contract (creating, storing and retrieving records in this case), not how it achieves this. If you create your unit tests smartly (against an interface, not a class directly), you can test different implementations, as they also have to adhere to the contract of the interface.

On the other hand, in some cases you have to actually verify how stuff gets persisted (maybe some other process relies on the data being in the right format in that database?). Now you can't just rely on getting the correct record back from the class, instead you have to verify that it is correctly stored in the database. And the most direct way to do that is querying the database itself.

> Now you don't only care about the class adhering to its contract (create, store and retrieve), but also how it achieves this (since that persisted data needs to adhere to another interface). However, now the tests are dependent on both the class interface **and** the storage format, so it will be hard to reuse them fully. (Some might call these kinds of tests "integration tests".)

Comment: @downvoters: might you tell me your reasons so I can improve on the aspects you think my answer is lacking?