# What is the best practice of testing methods which call each other?

Tags: unit-testing

Say I have a method A which calls a method B and does one additional thing. The B method behaves differently in 10 different cases and I have a broad unit test describing it. And now I want to test my method A. What is the best practice to do that? Should I run the same test with all 10 cases for method A to make sure that proper method is run? It sounds like an overkill. Or maybe I should test only one of that cases? But there's a risk that in future I'll write some method which will be quite similar to B and there will occure a bug which won't be detected by the test. Or maybe there are some ways of checking that my B method was fired just by registering its name? Maybe that's quite simple problem, but I'm new in unit testing and I haven't found any clear answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I test the functionality of a function that uses other functions in it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225323/how-should-i-test-the-functionality-of-a-function-that-uses-other-functions-in-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're question isn't completely clear to me, so I'm making the following assumptions:

1. Method `A` and `B` are both "public",
2. Method `B` has 10 execution paths through it and 10 test cases covering those paths,
3. Method `A` calls `B` via at least one of its execution paths.
4. There are paths through `B` that are not used by `A`.

Also, I'm going to have to ignore "But there's a risk that in future I'll write some method which will be quite similar to B and there will occur a bug which won't be detected by the test" as I don't see how it's related to either your question or testing `A` and `B`.

The first thing I'd say is *do not try to mock B, unless you absolutely have to*. This is a classic testing newbie mistake that many folk make. You only want to isolate `A` from `B` if the latter has side-effects or is slow. If you mock out `B`, you'll simply be testing `A` against the mock functionality, rather than `B`'s real functionality and you'll miss bugs as a result.

The next thing to ask yourself is, can you repurpose some of those `B` test cases to have them test `A` and `B` together? So if you have four paths through `B` that are used by `A`, test those paths via testing `A`. There's a huge caveat here though. Bear in mind that each of those tests will then tightly couple itself to existing functionality of `A` and `B`. If you later change `A` to have that functionality itself for example, you could end up not testing that part of `B`. Or changes might break tests just because the test is now brittle, not because you broke functionality, etc. As ever, there's a balance to be had between principle (test everything!) and pragmatism (I've got to ship this one day for there to be value in what I'm doing).

Comment: Deleted my answer after reading yours.  Expert.

Comment: @DanRayson, No, not the dreaded "expert" tag. :) Experts (think) they are masters of their domain; knowing all there is to know. After 35 years of software development, I still strive to be a beginner: there's just still so much to learn and so many good, new ideas coming through all the time. I'll accept "highly opinionated know-it-all", but never "expert" :) And I don't think you should delete your answer either. Let others decide on the relative worth of each.

Comment: @DavidArno, Is it true that as soon as we add an additional dependency into our SUT (method B), we are no longer unit testing, but instead, we are integration testing? I usually create two test projects per dll. A unit testing project, in which I mock out ALL dependencies in the SUT, and an integration testing project, in which I test the SUT with all its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new in unit testing and I haven't found any clear answer.

In many cases, there isn't a clear answer: just different trade offs that you need to evaluate for your own circumstances.

The talk you need to watch is [Integrated Tests are a Scam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDfX44fZoMc), by J.B. Rainsberger.  See also his [blog](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam).

You might also want to review some wisdom from [Kent Beck (2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153565/54734)

> I get paid for code that works, not for tests, so my philosophy is to test as little as possible to reach a given level of confidence

One of the motivations of unit tests is that they constrain your choice of implementations; the idea being that the tests give you a signal that your changes have produced an observable change in the behavior of your system.

So if you have a bunch of tests for `B`, and assume that those cover `A` as well, that's fine right up until the point that somebody decides to change the implementation of `A`.

If A `is-a` B; meaning that you are supposed to be able to replace a `B` with an `A` and still have a correct program, then a potentially useful trick is to write one suite of tests that gets invoked on both A and B.

```
void verifyThatItWorks(SystemUnderTest sut) {
    // this is where the implementation of the test lives
    // including the setup, activity, and verification
    // aka arrange, act, assert
}

@Test
void testB () {
    verifyThatItWorks(new B())
}

@Test
void testA () {
    verifyThatItWorks(new A())
}
```

In some programming languages, there are conveniences that allow you to manage
parallel copies of large test suites

```
abstract class AbstractSpecification {
    SystemUnderTest sut

    protected AbstractSpecification(SystemUnderTest sut) {
        this.sut = sut;
    }

    @Test behavior1 () {...}
    @Test behavior2 () {...} 
    // ...
}

class BSpecification extends AbstractSpecification {
    BSpecification () { super (new B()); }
}
class ASpecification extends AbstractSpecification {
    ASpecification () { super(new A()); }
}
```